# Set Validators on Nested FormControl objects with Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, angular-reactive-forms

How do I set validators on a nested FormControl with child objects?
This product below, actually has members: productId, productName, productDescription (coming from a dropdown select)
I want to set validators productId > 4 .

```
this.editSharedForm = this.formBuilder.group({
   'customerName':[null,[Validators.maxLength(50)],
   'customerPhone': [null, [Validators.maxLength(10)]],
   'product': new FormControl('')
```

Following is not working:

```
this.editSharedForm.get('product').get('productId').setValidators(Validators.min(5))

this.editSharedForm.get('product').value['productId'].setValidators(Validators.min(5))
```

Errors being Undefined error for first one, not a function for second command.

Comment: your control name is `product` where is `productId`?

Comment: Post the all (child formGroup) structure also!

Comment: Simply use `this.editSharedForm.get('product').setValidators(yourValidators)` and then call `this.editSharedForm.get('product').updateValueAndValidity()` in order to run the new validators.

Comment: 'product':this.formBuilder.group({productId:new FormControl(null)})

Comment: hi @AndreiGătej  feel free to place in answer, and I can send points, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use

```
this.editSharedForm.get('product').setValidators(yourValidators)
```

and then call

```
this.editSharedForm.get('product').updateValueAndValidity()
```

in order to **run** the new **validators**.